# javascript replace tokens using string split

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, token

Hi I have a text something like 
**"Welcome back @@Firstname @@Lastname. You Last accessed on @@Date"**

My objective is to replace these tokens with actual values.

So what i did was

```
var str = "Welcome back @@Firstname @@Lastname. You Last accessed on @@Date;
var data = str.split('@');
```

My idea was - once i do this, my data will have an array of values something like

```
["Welcome back", "@FirstName" , "@LastName", "You Last accessed on" , "@Date"]
```

Once i have this, i can easily replace the tokens because i will know which one are properties and which one are static string. But  fool i am  since JS has other ideas. 
it instead split it as  :

```
["Welcome back ", "", "Firstname ", "", "Lastname. You Last accessed on ", "", "Date"]
```

What am i doing wrong? or what is the best way to replace tokens in a string?

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780074/find-and-replace-tokens-in-javascript). Did not like the approach much. Not a fan of curly brackets. would like to do it the "@" way - Since it will be easy for Content authors

Comment: Split will split on every @ in the string

Comment: *My objective is to replace these tokens with actual values.* - I would think you'd want `.replace` rather than `.split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another *regex* option, split on `/@(@\w+)[^\w@]+/`, captures the name part while throwing off the first `@`, assuming the name identifiers are always made up of word characters:

```js
var str = "Welcome back @@Firstname @@Lastname. You Last accessed on @@Date;"
var data = str.split(/@(@\w+)[^\w@]+/);
console.log(data.filter(s => s !== ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split `"@"` characters which are followed by `"@"` characters

```js
var str = "Welcome back @@Firstname @@Lastname. You Last accessed on @@Date";

var res = str.split(/@(?=@)/);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Great answer. Had no idea you could split on regex

Comment: The `RegExp` can also be composed as `/[^@]@/`

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you  :). Agree with @AR7. Never knew about the split by regex. I cant accept this as an answer for another 8 minutes. Will do it after that :)

Comment: Curious as to reason for "downvote"? What is issue with Answer and how can Answer be improved?

Comment: I am not sure who did that downvote. but your answer is good for me. Can you explain the difference between the two regex  - the one in answer vs one in comment?

Comment: @guest271314 There's no point to ask for it, you'll never get an answer.

Comment: @NightMonger The `RegExp` at Answer splits `"@"` that is followed by `"@"`. The second  `RegExp` at comment splits `"@" character which is preceded by `"@"` character

Comment: @Kinduser There is a point to asking the question. Silence is an answer: the "downvote" lacks articulatable or comprehensible merit.

Answer (score 0):

As your delemiters end with a space, may split by space:

```
.split(" ")
```

And then iterate and replace all words beginning with @@

```
var replaceBy={
 lastname:"Doe",
 name:"John"
}

var result= input.split(" ").map(function(word){
 if(word[0]=="@" && word[1]=="@"){
   return replaceBy[word.substr(2)] || "error";
 }
 return word:
}).join(" ");
```

However, it might be easier to suround your identifiers with delemiters e.g.:

```
Hi @@lastname@@!
```

So you can do

```
.split("@@")
```

And every second element is automatically an identifier.

Comment: Unfortunately that may not be true. while it is true in the example above, i caould have a sentence like "Welcome @@Firstname,@@Lastname". @@ is the only token that i am sure of

Comment: @night monger but then its difficult to really get the identifier e.g. in your example, is it *Date* or *Date;* ?

Comment: that was a typo. the actual string was "Welcome back @@Firstname @@Lastname. You Last accessed on @@Date"; The tokens will always be a separate word in itself.

Comment: @night monger *Lastname* or *Lastname.* ? Whatsoever, psidom has a neat solution for that, much better then mys. I just leave it as a reference on how to replace, may delete it somewhen...

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the '@@' by some character followed by '@' like ',@' and then replace on that new character.

```js
var str = "Welcome back @@Firstname @@Lastname. You Last accessed on @@Date";
var data = str.replace(/@@/g, ',@').split(',');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -3):

Do this:

```
  data = str.replace("@@Firstname", "Robert").replace("@@Lastname","Polson").replace('@@Date','yesterday') ;
```